# store scope value, for it to be compared

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm doing a `ng-blur` and sending the current value of a `input` into a `function`. My problem is that I want to save the previous input value and pass that into the blur function, because if value is same no action.

```
<input type="text" class="input__text" name="name" ng-model="name" ng-blur="bluryLines(name)">

$scope.bluryLines = function(oldValue, value) {
   if (value !== '' | value !== oldValue) {
      console.log('some action');
   } else {
      console.log('is empty');
   }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-change to call your function and use ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" 
Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

```
<input type="text" class="input__text" name="name" ng-model="name" ng-change="bluryLines()" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/BLFj5iRtF3xUxIQEk8UT?p=preview

Comment: how do I pass the old value of the `name (or your myModel)`? When I use `name` to print out the value, as soon as I'm gone type it will change both. Or what am I missing here?

Comment: You only need the old value to compare with the actual value, right? If yes, then you don't need it anymore. Using ng-change directive and ng-model-options the function will be only called when the model value changes (name has changed).

Comment: Another thing: you don't need to pass the actual value to the function, because you don't need to compare it anymore.

Comment: @Dejan.S  Remember,  `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }` won't update the model `name` until `blur` occurs. So, there will be no change in the model `name` while you are typing in the text box. If you have any internal operation e.g `ng-if="name"` on some other element, the effect will take place after `blur`.

Comment: I know, I tend to pass values instead of getting it from `$scope`, same on submit I always pass in model.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a copy of the value in a variable at the end of the `$scope.bluryLines` function. You don't even need to pass any argument to the controller function.

```
var oldName;
$scope.bluryLines = function() {
   if ($scope.name !== '' | $scope.name !== oldName) {
      console.log('some action');
   } else {
      console.log('is empty');
   }
   // copy $scope.name
   oldName = angular.copy($scope.name);
};
```

See this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9d6o4o7tDmpSPhyGWtCi?p=preview).

Comment: I don't see how this will copy the old value?

Comment: @Dejan.S You keep `$scope.name` in the oldName i.e `oldName = angular.copy($scope.name);`. See the plunker I shared with you. On the other hand, with this approach, if you need separate input boxes to call the same `$scope.bluryLines` function on `ng-blur`, then you need to pass some argument against the modal and change the oldName to something like array(map type) to keep input box's modal value.